# SC2207 Bash array assignment from subshell not splitting as expected

Tags: arrays, bash, subshell, ifs, shellcheck

I have been populating an array using:

```sh
AWS_STS_CREDS=( $(aws sts ...) )
```

This raises [shellcheck error SC2207](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2207)

> Prefer mapfile or read -a to split command output

But the recommendation does not work as expected.

```sh
IFS=" " read -r -a AWS_STS_CREDS <<< "$(
  aws sts assume-role \
    --role-arn ${AWS_ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name ${AWS_SESSION_NAME} \
    --query '[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]' \
    --output text
)"

echo "Array contains ${#AWS_STS_CREDS[@]} elements"
#> Array contains 1 elements

echo "${AWS_STS_CREDS[0]}"
#> ASIAV2R3U... 4gXdep/GN... FwoGZXI...
```

I have also tried removing the quotes around the subcommand.

At first it appears as though the set *IFS* is having no effect but the below works:

```sh
IFS=" " read -r -a AWS_STS_CREDS <<< "$(echo '1 2 3')"
```

I am overlooking something but I'm having trouble identifying the problem and would like to understand the behaviour.

Comment: Add some lines of `aws ... | cat -A` to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember that tip! The output is clearly tab delimited. I had checked before by simply redirecting to a file. I overlooked that my editor is translating them to spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Cyrus's suggestion, piping the subcommand output to `cat -A` clearly shows it is tab delimited. Indicated by `^I`

```sh
echo "${AWS_STS_CREDS[0]}"
#> ASIAV2R3U...^I4gXdep/GN...^IFwoGZXI...
```

Amending the script as follows works as expected:

```sh
IFS=$'\t' read -r -a AWS_STS_CREDS <<< "$(
  aws sts assume-role \
    --role-arn ${AWS_ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name ${AWS_SESSION_NAME} \
    --query '[Credentials.AccessKeyId,Credentials.SecretAccessKey,Credentials.SessionToken]' \
    --output text
)"

echo "Array contains ${#AWS_STS_CREDS[@]} elements"
#> Array contains 3 elements

echo "${AWS_STS_CREDS[0]}"
#> ASIAV2R3U...
```